# Self collisions using IrisInConfigurationSpace

Tags: drake

I'm using Drake's `IrisInConfiguration` space with default options to create a collision-free `HPolyhedron` for my robot. When sampling the resulting polyhedron using `hpoly.UniformSample`, I notice that the robot does a good job avoiding collision with other geometries in the scene, but on rare occasions it collides with itself.

You can see the forces created by self-collision in the first image, as well as the collision geometries in the second image.

Is this due to `options.num_collision_infeasible_samples` being too small or might there be some misconfiguration elsewhere that prevents Iris from checking collisions between these two links?

[image: self collision]
[image: collision geometry]

Comment: Increasing `num_collision_infeasible_samples` did not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: fwiw -- I have a WIP interface (called "IrisBuilder") [here]((https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19514).  It should land in Drake soon.

Comment: Thanks @RussTedrake. I saw in your notebook the option to have `use_existing_regions_as_obstacles`. Is the intent to grow any new regions away from the existing graph of collision free regions? In my own experiments I found that without such a heuristic, the Iris regions like to overlap each other a lot and the graph becomes full of cliques which makes shortest path optimization slow.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We have a better solution for this coming soon, too.

If you'd like to drop me an email, I'd be interested in hearing more about your application (and might be able to make some better recommendations)

Comment: Thanks @RussTedrake. Unfortunately my employer is very secretive. At this point, I can only say that we are trying to insert the robot through an opening inside a large container filled with clutter and we are trying to plan around the clutter inside. I'm currently having success by using heuristics to guess the order of convex regions to visit (Dijkstra's algorithm through the Chebyshev centers) and then using KinematicTrajectoryOptimization to constrain the control points to visit these regions and their intersections in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IrisInConfigurationSpace can use collision filter groups... you might want to confirm that whatever is making that render is using the same collision filter groups as Iris.  (but if you haven't set any filters, then they should be using the same by default).

Otherwise, I do think that increasing `num_collision_infeasible_samples` would be the right solution.

I've been thinking about having a method to refine the regions based on any new counter-examples that might be discover after the original call to IrisInConfigurationSpace. Precisely because if you do happen upon a counter-example, it would be useful to be able to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't specifying any collision filter groups manually, so I guess this really is an issue about a counter-example slipping through the probabilistic check.